# Style is not working in angular JS

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to display input fields pink before entering values and green after values are entered. But, when I am applying style it is working only for first row. Is there any error?

```
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
input.ng-invalid {
    background-color:pink;
}
input.ng-valid {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycont">
    <form name="myform">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="facultyid" ng-model="faculty.id" required /><br><span style="color:red" ng-show="myform.facultyid.$touched && myform.facultyid.$invalid">Id is required</span></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Salary:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.salary" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="agree" required>Agree terms and conditions</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button ng-disabled="myform.$invalid" ng-click="addfaculty(faculty)">ADD</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Plunker please.

Comment: Have you not used any condition to change the style? It is set as red by default which does not change.

Comment: no. I used conditions ng-valid and ng-invalid

Comment: Can you add `required` in all input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```js
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.submit = function() {
        return false;
      };      
  }]);
```

```css
input.ng-invalid {
background-color:pink;
}
input.ng-valid {
background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="formExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate>
   <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="facultyid" ng-model="faculty.id" required /><br><span style="color:red" ng-show="myform.facultyid.$touched && myform.facultyid.$invalid">Id is required</span></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.name" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Faculty Salary:</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="faculty.salary" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="agree" required>Agree terms and conditions</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><button ng-disabled="myform.$invalid" ng-click="addfaculty(faculty)">ADD</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
  </form>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But only after clicking add,all the fields are turning red.I need it when I run the code.And also I need to use button despite submit.Is there a way?